# Input String was not in Correct Format (C#: Radio buttons conversion)

Tags: c#, radio-button, format, converters

I am making a simple program where I/the user will select a number (the radio button) and when the "Click" is clicked, a message box will appear and show the result.

i am almost there but everytime I click "Click", an error occurs and says: Input string is not in correct format.

What would be the problem?

Here's my code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
        int multiply = 20;

        String rad1 = Convert.ToString(radioButton1); 

        int rad11 = Convert.ToInt16(rad1); //it says here that this is a wrong format.
       // int product;

            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                int product = rad11 * multiply;
                String answer = Convert.ToString(product);
                MessageBox.Show(answer);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception eb)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eb.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which value are you trying to read when you do `String rad1 = Convert.ToString(radioButton1);`?  If it's the radio button's text, then Nikhil Agrawal just gave you the fix.  Otherwise, let us know which value you are looking for.

Comment: What is the value of `rad1`?  Is it a number?  If it isn't, or if the number is larger than what a `short` can hold, then you will get the error.

Comment: hello, rad1 is actually a radiobutton. and i want that radiobutton to be converted into an int so I can multiply it to 20 everytime I click "Click"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Winforms or ASP then you need to do

```
String rad1 = radioButton1.Text;
```

If you are using WPF then you need to do

```
String rad1 = Convert.ToString(radioButton1.Content);
```

Comment: @sstan: Still need it for WPF because content is object type.

Comment: hello! I am sorry, I placed the comment on the wrong statement. Please see again my code. I am sorry.

Comment: @Naomi: what value do you get in `rad1`

Comment: rad1 is actually a radio button with a text of "20". i want to convert that radio button into an int so that I can multiply it to number 20. (int multiply = 20).

Comment: @Naomi: then use Nikhil Agrawal's answer.  It will fix your problem.  You are not getting the radio button's text.  You are basically doing `radioButton1.ToString()` instead, which is not what you want.

Comment: @Naomi: What is happening is that you convert radiobutton to string so in rad1 variable you get `System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton` which when you try to convert to int gives your exception.

Comment: Hello again guys! Just tried what Nikhil Agrawal's answer and it worked! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

what value u getting when debugging in Convert.ToString(radioButton1)?
according to me you cannot convert radiobutton instead you can convert the text or you can say value